# Searching in folder

Tags: java, file, search

I want to create a method that will search files by name. I have variable with a name and I need method that search file with that name in one folder. This is my sample code:

```
public class Searching {

    File file = new File("C:/Dane DMS/");
    static ArrayList <String>listaPlikowJava = new ArrayList <String> ();
    public void szukanie(File file)
    {
        for (File szukany : file.listFiles())
        {
            if(szukany.isDirectory())
                szukanie(szukany);
            else {
                String temp[] = szukany.getName().split(".");
                if (temp[1].equals("a")) listaPlikowJava.add(szukany.getName());
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about this idea?

Comment: where is the variable with the file name to be searched?

Comment: I think you're trolling the people here, posting code with naming different than English.

Comment: omg, this is my choice how I named my variables.

Comment: The variable names are part of the code documentation and if you're sharing code, you should make sure your documentation is understandable by the people you're sharing code with.

Comment: Rather than putting the found files in a static member, you should probably return the `List` from the method. This will make your code easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: Ok. Next time I named my variables in English for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good one, but it is a more clear to use `listFiles(FileFilter filter)`

```
public class MyFileFilter implements FileFilter {
   public boolean accept(File pathname) {
     if (pathname.isDirectory())
       return false;
     else {
       String temp[] = pathname.getName().split(".");
       if (temp[1].equals("a")) return true;
     }
   }
}
```