# Files searching in Java

Tags: java, file, search, directory

Because I asked wrong question [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105401/searching-in-folder), I want to correct my intention. How can I find file by name in specified folder? I have a variable with a name of this file and i want to find it in specified folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751335/using-file-listfiles-with-filenameextensionfilter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the simplest thing that works is:

```
String dirPath = "path/to/directory";
String fileName = "foo.txt";
boolean fileExistsInDir = new File( dirPath, fileName ).exists();
```

File is just a placeholder for a location in the file system. The location does not have to [exist](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

Comment: This is cool - it's funny I didn't think of it earlier. However, this approach won't work if you need to search recursively.

Comment: Sure, recursive searching is more involved. The question does state "find by name in specified folder" though.

Comment: "find by name in specified folder" reminds me of the Unix `find /folder -name 'file_name'` ;)

Comment: Indeed, but doing that correctly from Java would be a lot of work :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Finding files in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) as a starting point. It should have everything that you are looking for - ask another specific question if you get stuck.